# Trying to find what goes in front of function to print all members in guild

Tags: discord-jda

I feel that I am so close to printing all members of a guild my bot is in. But the problem is I can't find what it needs to go in front of `getGuildByID().getMembers()`. It always shows "cannot resolve X" and I don't know what other variable goes in front because all of the code I am looking at uses these but for mine it doesn't work.

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;

import java.util.List;

public class Members {
    public String AllMembers() {
        List<Member> MemberList = Guild.getGuildByID(ID).getMembers();
        for(int i = 0; i<MemberList.size();i++)
        {
        System.out.println(MemberList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

I did try switching it out with `Event` or `event` but neither of those worked for me. It might be a problem with the code setting up the bot but of course I am not sure. I did enable intents for `SERVER_MEMBERS` but the only problem is what comes at the beginning of the methods.